# Data visualisation of boxplot and transparent histogram overplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Ok lets take some basic data:

```
data <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 50, sd = 10)
data <- round(data, digits = 0)
```

We can plot these with:

```
boxplot(data, horizontal = TRUE)
stripchart(data, vertical = FALSE, method = 'jitter', add = TRUE, pch=16, col='blue')
```

[image]
We can `method =  jitter`, `overplot` or `stack`. [link](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/graphics/stripchart)

When we use `stack`, we see the various counts of each, like a histogram. Now we want to create a link with a single point per count (as represented by the overplot) with a shading of the counts. How can one apply a shading to a stripchart to represent the counts of data.
Solutions can be in base R or with `ggplot2`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean with 'shading of the counts'? Is it a histogram-like structure?

Comment: Related post for ggplot: [Combination Boxplot and Histogram using ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551582/combination-boxplot-and-histogram-using-ggplot2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after? A transparent histogram over your boxplot?

```
data <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 50, sd = 10)
data <- round(data, digits = 0)


boxplot(data, horizontal = TRUE)
stripchart(data, vertical = FALSE, method = 'stack', 
           add = TRUE, pch=15, col=rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2), cex = 0.7)
```

[image]