# Overlaying boxplot with histogram in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I want to create a similar chart as shown below with R script:

[image]

taken from: https://community.tableau.com/thread/194440

this is my code in R :

```
library(ggplot2)

ifile <- read.table("C:/ifiles/test.txt", skip = 2, header = TRUE, sep="\t")
ifileVI <- data.frame(ifile["VI"], ifile["Site"])
x<-quantile(ifileVI$VI,c(0.01,0.99))
data_clean <- ifileVI[bfileVI$VI >=x[1] & ifileVI$VI <=x[2],]

p <- ggplot(data_clean, aes(x = Site, y = VI, group=Site)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.05)

p
```

however im getting the following error:

```
Error: stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
```

bfileVI:

```html
Id     VI Site
WFR1 2.91 1
WFR1 2.89 2
WFR1 2.86 3
WFR1 2.91 4
WFR1 2.87 1
WFR1 2.67 2
WFR1 2.76 3
WFR1 2.74 4
WFR1 2.98 4
WFR1 2.89 3
WFR1 2.55 4
WFR1 2.96 3
WFR1 2.71 1
WFR1 2.98 2
WFR1 2.89 3
WFR2 2.55 2
WFR2 2.86 4
WFR2 2.91 3
WFR2 287 1
WFR2 2.74 2
WFR2 2.98 1
WFR2 2.89 2
WFR2 2.55 3
WFR2 2.96 4
WFR2 2.71 1
WFR2 2.86 2
WFR2 2.91 3
WFR2 287 4
WFR2 2.67 1
WFR2 2.76 2
WFR2 2.74 3
WFR2 2.98 4
WFR2 2.89 1
WFR2 2.55 2
WFR2 2.96 3
WFR2 2.71 4
WFR2 2.98 1
WFR2 2.89 2
WFR2 2.55 3
WFR2 2.86 4
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput()`

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551582/combination-boxplot-and-histogram-using-ggplot2 -- doesn't put the charts on top of each other, but I think overlapping them like in the example is not a good idea... overwhelms the brain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to replace histogram with rectangles to generate a plot like this:

[image]

---

### How to do this:

#### Generate random data

```
df <- data.frame(State = LETTERS[1:3],
                 Y = sample(1:10, 30, replace = TRUE),
                 X = rep(1:10, 3))
```

#### Replace histogram with rectangles

```
library(ggplot2)

# You can plot geom_histogram or bar (pre-counted stats)
ggplot(df, aes(X, Y)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    facet_grid(State ~ .)
# Or you can plot similar figure with geom_rect
ggplot(df)  +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = X - 0.4, xmax = X + 0.4, ymin = 0, ymax = Y)) +
    facet_grid(State ~ .)
```

#### Add boxplot

To add boxplot we need to:

1. Flip coordinates (function `coord_flip`)
2. Switch X and Y values in `geom_rect`

Code:

```
ggplot(df)  +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = Y, ymin = X - 0.4, ymax = X + 0.4)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(X, Y)) +
    coord_flip() +
    facet_grid(State ~ .)
```

Result:

[image]

#### Final plot code with nicer visuals

```
ggplot(df)  +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = Y, ymin = X - 0.4, ymax = X + 0.4),
              fill = "blue", color = "black") +
    geom_boxplot(aes(X, Y), alpha = 0.7, fill = "salmon2") +
    coord_flip() +
    facet_grid(State ~ .) +
    theme_classic() +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:max(df$X))
```

Comment: Hi, I have shown my sample data in blufileVf2 (in my answer) how do I adapt your script to process that file? your Y is my Vf2 Bins and X is frequency? there are 4 discrete "sites" 1,2,3,4

Comment: @Adhil add more data and using **dput** function (not picture)

Comment: sorry I dont understand, I'm new to r :)

Comment: @Adhil paste your data to question (not a picture, there's no use of it)

Comment: I have pasted the data

Comment: I have added some changes please advise

Answer (score 4):

A good example where `ggstance` package comes in handy.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_boxploth(aes(y = 3), width = 2, color = "blue", lwd = 2, alpha = .5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_wrap(~Species, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're getting `Error: stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic.` because you can't specify `y` in the aesthetic of a histogram. If you want to mix plots that have different parameters, you need to supply distinct aesthetics. I'll demonstrate with `iris` like so:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.05) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = 3, y = Sepal.Width))
```

Unfortunately, the default for boxplots is vertical, for histograms is horizontal, and `coord_flip()` is all-or-nothing, so you're left with this awful thing: [image]

Best I can figure out is instead of having them overlap, put one on top of the other with the `gridExtra` package:

```
a <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.05) 

b <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = "", y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  coord_flip()

grid.arrange(a,b,nrow=2)
```

which gives us something pretty good: [image]

Comment: The link @mysteRious provides above gives further details, e.g. on how to match axes ranges which are currently misaligned in your plot (e.g. `2.0` in the top plot does not line up with `2.0` in the bottom plot).